# google-cloud-sdk - Fatal errors on both update and attempted reinstall Mac OSX 10.7.5

Tags: python, macos, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Install worked fine prior to 01-15-14 update.   Update fails due to fatal python errors.

Manual download and install produces same errors.  Running install as sudo produces same errors.

What steps will reproduce the problem?

```
curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash | bash
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100  3707  100  3707    0     0   5777      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 17162
    curl -f https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz > tmp.K8axYW7pd9/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100  332k  100  332k    0     0   339k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  359k

    Directory to extract under (this will create a directory google-cloud-sdk) (/Users/username):GoogleCompute
    tar -C GoogleCompute -xvf tmp.K8axYW7pd9/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
    x google-cloud-sdk/
    x google-cloud-sdk/.install/
    x google-cloud-sdk/.install/core.snapshot.json
    x google-cloud-sdk/.install/.download/
    x google-cloud-sdk/.install/core.manifest
    x google-cloud-sdk/bin/
    x google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/
    x google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/.install_configurations
    x google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/.default_components
    x google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/setup.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/prerun.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/print_env_info.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/RELEASE_NOTES
    x google-cloud-sdk/README
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/argcomplete/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/argcomplete/my_argparse.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/argcomplete/completers.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/argcomplete/scripts/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/argcomplete/scripts/python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/argcomplete/scripts/register-python-argcomplete
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/argcomplete/scripts/activate-global-python-argcomplete
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/argcomplete/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/argcomplete/my_shlex.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/gcloud.yaml
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/gcloud.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/config/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/config/list.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/config/set.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/config/unset.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/config/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/root/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/root/interactive.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/root/version.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/root/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/auth/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/auth/list.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/auth/enable_google_repos.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/auth/activate_refresh_token.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/auth/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/auth/login.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/auth/revoke.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/components/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/components/list.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/components/restore.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/components/remove.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/components/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/components/update.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/calliope/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/calliope/base.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/calliope/actions.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/calliope/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/calliope/exceptions.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/util/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/util/files.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/util/console_io.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/util/platforms.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/util/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/util/edit.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/metrics.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/log.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/VERSION
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/config.json
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/schemas.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/local_state.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/update_manager.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/snapshots.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/installers.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/cli.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/credentials/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/credentials/flow.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/credentials/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/credentials/gitp2d.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/credentials/oauth2_landing.html
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/credentials/store.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/credentials/gce.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/credentials/legacy.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/config.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/properties.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/setup_command.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/debug.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/basetest.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/app.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/file_util.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/shellutil.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/datelib.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/appcommands.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/run_script_module.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/resources.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/google/apputils/stopwatch.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/serializer.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/resolver.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/events.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/nodes.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/loader.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/representer.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/parser.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/emitter.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/cyaml.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/dumper.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/composer.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/reader.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/scanner.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/tokens.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/constructor.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/yaml/error.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/django_orm.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/appengine.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/tools.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/old_run.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/file.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/multistore_file.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/anyjson.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/keyring_storage.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/gce.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/locked_file.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/crypt.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/client.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/util.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/oauth2client/xsrfutil.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/socks/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/socks/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/httplib2/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/httplib2/iri2uri.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/httplib2/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/httplib2/LICENSE
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/httplib2/cacerts.txt
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/uritemplate/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/uritemplate/uritemplate.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/uritemplate/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/apiclient/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/apiclient/mimeparse.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/apiclient/http.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/apiclient/oauth.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/apiclient/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/apiclient/model.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/apiclient/push.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/apiclient/channel.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/apiclient/errors.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/apiclient/discovery.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/apiclient/schema.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/ChangeLog
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/setup.cfg
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/MANIFEST.in
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/gflags2man.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/gflags_validators.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/README
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/__init__.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/NEWS
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/PKG-INFO
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/Makefile
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/setup.py
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/AUTHORS
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/COPYING
    x google-cloud-sdk/lib/gflags/LICENSE
    x google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
    x google-cloud-sdk/install.bat
    x google-cloud-sdk/LICENSE

    GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
    Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

    The Google Cloud SDK is currently in developer preview. To help improve the
    quality of this product, we collect anonymized data on how the SDK is used.
    You may choose to opt out of this collection now (by choosing 'N' at the below
    prompt), or at any time in the future by running the following command:
        gcloud config --global-only set disable_usage_reporting true

    Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (Y/n)?  y


    This will install all the core command line tools necessary for working with
    the Google Cloud Platform.

    If you are developing an App Engine application, please select the 
    language your application is written in.  This will install the 
    required tools and runtimes for working in that language.  If 
    necessary, you can add and remove languages later through the gcloud 
    component manager.
      [1]  Java
      [2]  Python and PHP
      [3]  Go
      [4]  No App Engine (you can install App Engine tools later)
    Please enter your numeric choice (4):  2


    The following components will be installed:
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | App Engine Launcher Application for Mac              |      1.8.9 |  7.4 MB |
        | App Engine SDK for Python and PHP                    |      1.8.9 | 35.4 MB |
        | Big Query Command Line Tool                          |     2.0.17 |  < 1 MB |
        | Big Query Command Line Tool (Platform Specific)      |     2.0.17 |  < 1 MB |
        | Cloud SDK Core Command Line Tools                    |          1 |         |
        | Cloud SDK Core Libraries (Platform Specific)         | 2013.11.19 |  < 1 MB |
        | Cloud SDK for Python and PHP Developers              |          1 |         |
        | Cloud SQL Admin Command Line Interface               | 2013.12.17 |  < 1 MB |
        | Cloud Storage Command Line Tool                      |       3.40 |  1.7 MB |
        | Cloud Storage Command Line Tool (Platform Specific)  |       3.40 |  < 1 MB |
        | Compute Engine Command Line Tool                     |     1.13.0 |  < 1 MB |
        | Compute Engine Command Line Tool (Platform Specific) |     1.13.0 |  < 1 MB |
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Creating update staging area...


    Installing: App Engine Launcher Application for Mac ... Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 283, in <module>
        Install(pargs.disable_installation_options)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 247, in Install
        components = InstallComponents(to_install)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 269, in InstallComponents
        components.update(component_ids=component_ids, allow_no_backup=True)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/calliope/__init__.py", line 925, in __call__
        return self._Execute(cli_mode=False, kwargs=kwargs)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/calliope/__init__.py", line 960, in _Execute
        cli_mode=cli_mode)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/calliope/__init__.py", line 702, in Run
        result = command_instance.Run(args)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/gcloud/sdktools/components/update.py", line 38, in Run
        manager.Update(args.component_ids, allow_no_backup=args.allow_no_backup)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 88, in _TryFunc
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 465, in Update
        self._InstallFunction(staging_state, diff))
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 377, in _UpdateAndPrint
        action_func(component.id)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 384, in Inner
        return install_state.Install(diff.latest, component_id)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/local_state.py", line 73, in _TryFunc
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/local_state.py", line 409, in Install
        files = self._GetInstaller(snapshot).Install(component_id)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/installers.py", line 78, in Install
        return self._InstallTar(component)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/installers.py", line 115, in _InstallTar
        url, self.__download_directory, self.__sdk_root)
      File "/Users/username/GoogleCompute/GoogleCompute/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/google/cloud/sdk/core/updater/installers.py", line 146, in DownloadAndExtractTar
        with file_utils.Context(tarfile.open(name=download_file_path)) as tar:
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'
```

Comment: If you install ActiveState python and change system path ordering to override Apple's built-in python, then installation is clean and successful.  But installation was easy, clean, and successful prior to the 01-15-14 update, without having to install another python interpreter...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the traceback, is it possible that you have another module named `tarfile` shadowing the standard library `tarfile` module?

On my computer, I see:

```
>>> import tarfile
>>> tarfile.__file__
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tarfile.pyc'
>>> tarfile.open
<bound method type.open of <class 'tarfile.TarFile'>>
```

If `tarfile.__file__` isn't in a subdirectory of `/lib/python*`, you may have another module named `tarfile` shadowing the standard library module.