# Create blob from URL in gae using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to create a blob from an image URL but I can't figure out how to do that.

I've already read the documentation from google about creating blob, but it talks only about creating blob from a form and using `blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_photo').`
I read some question over there but I didn't found anything that could help me.

My app has a list of image URL and I want to save theese images into the blobstore so I will able to serve them afterwards. I think that blobstore is the solution but if there is a better way to do this, please tell me!

**EDIT**
I'm trying to use google cloud storage:

```
class Upload(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Upload blob from url')
        url = 'https://500px.com/photo/163151085/evening-light-by-jack-resci'
        url_preview = 'https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/163151085/q%3D50_w%3D140_h%3D140/d3b8d92296f9381a91f6d41b1c607c92?v=3'
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url_preview)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            doSomethingWithResult(result.content)
        self.response.write(url_preview)


def doSomethingWithResult(content):
    gcs_file_name = '/%s/%s' % ('provajack-1993', 'prova.jpg')
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type('prova.jpg')[0]

    with cloudstorage.open(gcs_file_name, 'w', content_type=content_type, options={b'x-goog-acl': b'public-read'}) as f:
        f.write(content)

    return images.get_serving_url(blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs' + gcs_file_name))
```

(found in stackoverflow) but this code give me an error:

```
*File "/base/data/home/apps/e~places-1993/1.394547465865256081/main.py", line 54, in doSomethingWithResult
    with cloudstorage.open(gcs_file_name, 'w', content_type=content_type, options={b'x-goog-acl': b'public-read'}) as f:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'*
```

I can't understand why. I have to set something in cloud storage?

Comment: Why don't you try google cloud storage instead of blobstore?

Comment: Download and read the file using gae's urlfetch class and then create a new file inside gcs bucket. Give appropriate permissions to the gcs bucket in-order to make the bucket objects available to all. Then generate a gcs object serving url, give that url to all your users..

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edited my answer becouse it doesn't work! Can you help me?

Comment: Well, the method is there: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open.

Comment: You could have a module shadowing issue or a name conflict, try debugging it using the technique described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167528/google-cloud-sdk-fatal-errors-on-both-update-and-attempted-reinstall-mac-osx-1

Comment: Yes, it was a name conflict! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [`cloudstorage.open()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open) clearly exists, so the error likely indicates some library/naming conflict in your environment.

A method for debugging such conflict is described in this post: [google-cloud-sdk - Fatal errors on both update and attempted reinstall Mac OSX 10.7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167528/google-cloud-sdk-fatal-errors-on-both-update-and-attempted-reinstall-mac-osx-1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to use google cloud storage but I have some problem when I call the method open (as I edited in my question)